# When should you write "answer" versus "response"?

Tags: word-choice, differences

In context, when would it be appropriate to use "answer" or "response"? I always tend to use "answer" personally, but I have always this nagging feeling I could be wrong.

Comment: Nice question. (← an example of a response to the question which is not an answer)

Comment: Ironically, it contribute to understand the answer.

Comment: In most forums, there are responses (vaguely related to the initial post), on StackExchange, there are answers (directly addressing the question, in a comprehensive and definitive manner).

Comment: A response can be an answer or a well-thought reaction. The best translation of "answer" in French would be "réponse".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

*Response* is a very broad term, and includes all reactions to a stimulus.

*Answer* is more specifically a *response* to a direct question.

One can always *respond* to anything (an event, an injury, a letter, a speech, a question...) but one can only *answer* a question. As Emanuil said, it's also possible to respond to a question without actually answering it; listen to politicians being interviewed.

Comment: Possibly amusing aside: it's also possible to respond to a statement, "answering" it like it's a question. For example, athletes do this all the time when being interviewed. Not that this is correct...just mentioning it :)

Comment: What about if someone says _"Answer me!"_ but only wants some kind of _response_?

Comment: Isn't "respond" also less used and more formal than "answer" ?

Answer (score 5):

"response" requires something you are responding to and it doesn't have to contain an answer. You can respond to a question without answering it.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly answer would imply some kind of result?

Answer (score 1):

"Response" is from Latin (*responsum*), while "answer" is from Old English (noun: *andswaru*, verb: *answarian*.).

I always use Fowler's rule: Prefer the Saxon word to the Romance.